# Dequeue an array in perl with thread::queue

Tags: perl, multithreading

I am trying to process data with a set of threads and enqueue it with another, currently the enqueueing and dequeueing process doesn't seem to be working

Any thoughs??

```
sub process() {
    while (my @DataElement = $DataQueue->dequeue()) {
        print "\t".$DataElement[0]."\n";
    }
}
```

I use the following to enqueue the data

```
my @l;
push(@l, $directories.$suffix);
push(@l, "testclass");
push(@l, $eachFile);
$DataQueue->enqueue(\@l);
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you accessing an array reference without dereferencing it? Try

```
while (my $DataElementRef = $DataQueue->dequeue()) {
    my @DataElement = @$DataElementRef;
    print "\t".$DataElement[0]."\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't solve the larger issue of not being able to print out anything, There must be something wrong somewhere else

Comment: something in the while statement seems to be wrong and not throwing an error

Answer (score 1):

@l is not shared, so you can't pass it's reference to another thread. Use threads::shared.

Comment: Ordinary scalars are added to queues as they are.

If not already thread-shared, the other complex data types will be cloned (recursively, if needed, and including any blessings and read-only settings) into thread-shared structures before being placed onto a queue.